# Trying to get bind working for combination of State and Delayed monad

Tags: f#, monads, free-monad, recursive-type

If the answer to this is "you are going about it all wrong", by all means let me know a more proper way. I had code which was structured like this:

```
type Res<'T> =
    | E of (DC -> 'T)
    | V of 'T
```

Now this type was primarily used directly, with a lot of inline code that did manual per-case binding, which is a lot of boilerplate I am trying to get rid of, so I figured I turn it into a computation expression. It wasn't too hard to get *map*, *bind* and *apply* right.

State was carried along through DC but this was cumbersome to get right, so I changed it to the following, which is a common signature I see in discussions with the state monad.

```
type Res<'T> =
    | E of (DC -> DC * 'T)
    | V of 'T
```

Then I decided to take it to the next level and introduce the Delayed monad (or Eventually or whatever its name is). So I changed my type as follows, making it recursive:

```
type Res<'T> =
    | E of (DC -> DC * Res<'T>)
    | V of 'T
```

I tried some variants of the following, but keep getting:

> The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and 'Res<'a> -> Res<'b>'

(usually happens when I do not invoke the *return*, i.e. the `Res.E <|` below)

Or I can't seem to get my types right, the following (understandably) throws a type error, but I'm having a blind spot fixing it:

> This expression was expected to have type 'Res<'a>' but here has type 'DC * Res<'a>'.

```
let rec bind k res =
    match res with
    | Res.V v -> k v      // not delayed, should it be?
    | Res.E e -> 
        Res.E <| fun dc -> bind k (e dc)   // here's my error, on 'e dc'
         //(fun dc -> dc, bind f (e dc))
bind k res
```

I understand that the signature should be `('a -> Res<'b>) -> Res<'a> -> XRes<'b>`. The problem comes from getting the recursion right, at least in my head. I'm not even sure why I am feeding the result to `Res.E`, as in my understanding, the `k` continuation should already return this type anyway.

Also, I currently have the *return* as follows (following [Steve Horsfield](https://stevehorsfield.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/f-custom-monad-workflow-development/)):

```
let result v = Res.V v
```

But also noticed in some posts (notably the [hilarious Frankenfunctor](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/monadster/)) this:

```
let result v = Res.E <| fun dc -> dc, Res.V v
```

Maybe I am following a pattern I shouldn't have, but it seemed a good idea at the time, especially in trying to refactor zillions of boilerplate code and replace it with computation expressions, but perhaps I should stick to the direct evaluation, it fit in my head ;).

But I feel like I'm close... Any ideas?

Comment: In Haskell when one wants to apply two monads simultaneously, one uses Monad Transformers. I'm not sure if these are available in F# (or if they are even implementable in -- I've not implemented one myself). To get a handle on the concept, I've heard the paper [Monad Transformers Step by Step](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/personal/Transformers.pdf) is good.

Comment: @paul, thanks, I'll take a look. But somehow it doesn't seem too much to ask to have a one-dimensional implementation for keeping state _ánd_ having it delayed-evaluated.

Comment: there is a project on github that does some of it (I cannot find it right now but I think it uses [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl) - I'm sure someone remembers it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I'm not quite sure what the meaning of this monad would be, but</strike> 
Ok, after thinking about it a bit and reading the question's header :- ), I *do* understand what it means, and I can see how to build `bind` for it.

Your mistake is that the function wrapped in `Res.E` should return a tuple, but you're having it return just `Res<'b>` by recursively calling `bind`. And to mirror that, you're passing the result of `e` to recursive `bind` call in place of `Res<'b>` parameter, while `e` actually returns a tuple.

To do this correctly, you need to destructure the result of `e`, then pass second part to recursive `bind` call, and pair its result with the first part:

```
let rec bind (k: 'a -> 'b Res) (res: 'a Res) : 'b Res =
  match res with
  | V a -> k a
  | E e -> 
      E <| fun dc -> 
        let dc', res' = e dc 
        dc', bind k res'
```

The terminal case, I don't believe should be also delayed. That is, I don't see a reason for it. As far as I understand, the interpretation of the `V x` case should be "*a computation that doesn't change state and returns `x`*", in which case making it delayed doesn't add anything but an extra lambda-expression.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, this works! I wasn't (de-)tupling ;). As to its meaning, the nested type I use because of the advice here on constructing Delayed monad (with unit argument). The added `dc` argument and in the tuple is a state that is tagged along and popped/pushed with each execution. It follows (if I do it correctly) the pattern of a State monad. The whole thing is the combination of the two.

Comment: Btw, I'm not entirely sure whether it is now still tail-recursive, because the recur-call `bind` is now dependent on the result of `e dc`. But since that in itself is not recursive, I might be safe (though the depth here is not ridiculously deep, it may not matter in the end).

Comment: First, I edited the answer.
Second, I don't think you can ever make it tail-recursive under this definition, but the good news is, this thing is actually _not recursive at all_, if you think about it. Even though it calls `bind` within the definition of `bind`, that call is not truly "recursive" in the sense that `bind` doesn't call itself as part of its own evaluation. Instead, it returns a _closure_ that calls `bind` again.

Comment: Tx for the edit. Yes, you are entirely right. While it is recursive (the `rec` keyword), it uses continuations, which is the whole idea about writing this kind of bind expression. And at evaluation time, the closures get _recursively_ expanded/called but like you say, this ends up not really recursion ;). Btw, Jon Harrop once told me that _everything_ can be made tail recursive by, typically, using continuations.

Comment: Jon Harrop is correct. But to do that, you'll end up with a different type. That's why I said "_can't make tail recursive under this definition_".

Comment: Hmm, aren't nested types heap types anyway, and if any operation on their recursive (tree-like) structure is tailed, then it doesn't matter, right? I mean, the type itself, while recursive, is never a subject of tail-recursion, it is the functions that work with it.